# [ASP MVC]: Loose list values of view model on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel class :

```
public class IndexViewModel 
    {
        public IndexViewModel()
        {
            GridList = new List<GridModel>();
        }
        public List<Models.GridModel> GridList { get; set; }
        public string ATempProperty { get; set; }        
    }
```

> I pass it to my View successfully. On **submit** I want return it to an action with current ViewModel. But GridList is empty! What should I do to get list from view?
>   My View is something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="lll">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ATempProperty)        
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridList)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: You need to render each property of `GridList` in a `for` loop, but whats the point if they are all hidden controls anyway (generally better performance to just get the collection from the repository again on post back)

Comment: Why do you want to send the data back to the server that the server already have? Is the data changing on client side, if yes send only changed data? I hope you realize the point is to receive input from USER and send that data to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. But I get an error Message: 
**No parameterless constructor defined for this object.**
I have only one Action that is :

```
public ActionResult Edit(IndexViewModel ind)
        {    
            Do s.t .    
            return View();
        }
```

My ViewModel is :

```
public class GridModel
    {
        //public GridModel() { }
        public GridModel(List<object> GridDataSource, string GridName, int RecordCount,
            int PageRecordCount, int CurrentPageIndex, string Controller, string ActionName, string TargetID)
        {
            this.GridDataSource = GridDataSource;
            this.GridName = GridName;
            this.RecordCount = RecordCount;
            this.PageRecordCount = PageRecordCount;
            this.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPageIndex;
            this.Controller = Controller;
            this.ActionName = ActionName;
            this.TargetID = TargetID;


        }

        public List<string> classNameList = new List<string>();

        public List<object> GridDataSource { get; set; }
        public string GridName { get; set; }
        public int RecordCount { get; set; }
        public int PageRecordCount { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string TargetID { get; set; }

        private Dictionary<string, string> styles =
            new Dictionary<string, string>();

        private Dictionary<string, string> columns=
            new Dictionary<string, string>();        

        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public enum GridClasses
    {
            GridTable,
            GridHeader,
            GridBody,
            GridFooter,
            GridAlternativeRow,
            GridPager
    }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="GridClass">Chose yor class from GridModel.GridClass Enum</param>
        /// <param name="CssStyle">Enter full css attribute and values in a string format. Something like this :
        /// "color:red; font-size:10px;"</param>
        public void SetGridStyle(GridModel.GridClasses GridClass, string CssStyle)
        {
            if (styles.ContainsKey(GridClass.ToString()))
                styles[GridClass.ToString()] = CssStyle;
            else
                styles.Add(GridClass.ToString(), CssStyle);
        }    

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Return: The CSS style of getted class in CSS originall format.</returns>
        public string GetGridStyle(GridModel.GridClasses GridClass)
        {
            if (styles.ContainsKey(GridClass.ToString()))
            {
                return " GridContainer" + GridName + " ." + GridClass.ToString() + "{" + styles[GridClass.ToString()] + "}";
            }
            else
                return "";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Return: The CSS style of all classes of grid in CSS originall format.</returns>
        public string GetGridStyle()
        {
            string css = "";
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> d in styles)
                if(d.Key == GridClasses.GridAlternativeRow.ToString())
                    css += " #GridContainer" + GridName + " ." + GridName + d.Key + " tr:nth-child(even){" + d.Value + "} ";
                else if (d.Key == GridClasses.GridPager.ToString())
                css += " #GridContainer" + GridName + " ." + GridName + d.Key + " span{" + d.Value + "} ";
                else
                    css += " #GridContainer" + GridName + " ." + GridName + d.Key + "{" + d.Value + "} ";
            return css;
        }

        public void SetColumnsStyle(string ColumnName, string CssStyle)
        {
            if (columns.ContainsKey(ColumnName))
                columns[ColumnName] = CssStyle;
            else
                columns.Add(ColumnName, CssStyle);
        }

        public string GetColumnStyle()
        {
            string css = "";
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> d in columns)
                css += " #GridContainer" + GridName + " ." + GridName + d.Key + "{" + d.Value + "} ";
            return css;
        }

        public List<string> GetStyledColumns()
        {
            List<string> l = new List<string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> d in columns)
                l.Add(d.Key);
            return l;
        }

        public string EditController = "";
        public string EditAction = "";
        public bool IsInEditMode = false;
        public string GridCssClass = "webgrid";

    }
```

And my new View is :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, Model))
{
    int listNumber = 0;
    <div id="lll">

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ATempProperty)      
        @foreach(WebApplication1.Models.GridModel l in Model.GridList)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridList[listNumber].GridName);
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridList[listNumber].PageRecordCount);            
        }           
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: You have to have a parameterless constructor i.e. `public GridModel() {...};` And your code wont work anyway. It needs to be `for(int i = 0; i < Model.GridList.Count; i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridList[i].GridName) ...}`. But as I said previously, there is no point doing this and you just opening yourself up to being hacked and degrading you sites performance. Since you not changing any values of the `GridModel` properties (they are all hidden inputs), just get them from the database again when you post back

Comment: And why are you doing `var s = Request.Form["ATempProperty"];`? `ind.ATempProperty` already contains the value! And why are you doing `this.UpdateModel(ind);`? the model has already been bound! I suggest some quality time learning the basics of MVC is in order.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, var s = Request.Form["ATempProperty"]; was only for test. Actually I'm making a custom grid for MVC.net . So I have a List<object> as grid Datasource and I fetch properties by reflection. So I can't bind them to editable field on grid. At other hand I need to keep grids properties like Name, Pagerecourde EditableRecordList , ... . So the way to keep these is backing them to control and use them with FormCollection to retrieve grid.

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate over it and create hidden fields for properties:

```
 <div id="lll">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ATempProperty)
        @for(int i = 0 ; i< Model.GridList.Count; i++)
        {        
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.GridList[i].PropertyA)
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.GridList[i].PropertyB)
          ............................
          ............................
        }
    </div>
```